# Python memory error for a large data set

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, python-2.7, machine-learning

I want to generate a 'bag of words' matrix containing documents with the corresponding counts for the words in the document. In order to do this I run below code for initialising the bag of words matrix. Unfortunately I receive a memory error after x amounts of documents in the line where I read the document. Is there a better way of doing this, so that I can avoid the memory error? Please be aware that I would like to process a very large amount of documents ~ 2.000.000 with only 8 Gb of RAM.

```
def __init__(self, paths, words_count, normalize_matrix = False ,trainingset_size = None, validation_set_words_list = None):
    '''
    Open all documents from the given path.
    Initialize the variables needed in order
    to construct the word matrix.

    Parameters
    ----------
    paths: paths to the documents.
    words_count: number of words in the bag of words.
    trainingset_size: the proportion of the data that should be set to the training set.
    validation_set_words_list: the attributes for validation.
    '''

    print '################ Data Processing Started ################'

    self.max_words_matrix = words_count

    print '________________ Reading Docs From File System ________________'
    timer = time()
    for folder in paths:
        self.class_names.append(folder.split('/')[len(folder.split('/'))-1])
        print '____ dataprocessing for category '+folder
        if trainingset_size == None:
            docs = os.listdir(folder)
        elif not trainingset_size == None and validation_set_words_list == None:
            docs = os.listdir(folder)[:int(len(os.listdir(folder))*trainingset_size-1)]
        else:
            docs = os.listdir(folder)[int(len(os.listdir(folder))*trainingset_size+1):]
        count = 1
        length = len(docs)
        for doc in docs:
            if doc.endswith('.txt'):
                d = open(folder+'/'+doc).read()
                # Append a filtered version of the document to the document list.
                self.docs_list.append(self.__filter__(d))
                # Append the name of the document to the list containing document names.
                self.docs_names.append(doc)
                # Increase the class indices counter.
                self.class_indices.append(len(self.class_names)-1)

            print 'Processed '+str(count)+' of '+str(length)+' in category '+folder
            count += 1
```

Comment: This may be of use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model#BoW_with_the_hashing_trick

Comment: For every word you can increase dictionary (you can create defaultdict) value, something like this words_count[word] = words_count[word]+1 and at the end of the file save the dict.

Comment: `self.docs_list.append(self.__filter__(d))` - what does `__filter__` do? You aren't trying to retain 2M docs in memory?

Comment: It's worth noting that the main space optimization of the BoW model does not generally apply in Python. After all, another reference to the `2` number is just as big as another reference to the `"likes"` string. The only way to get the optimization is to use an `array.array`, `numpy.ndarray`, or similar for each document vector instead of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible. Also, Python doesn't automatically get the space benefits you're expecting from BoW. Plus, I think you're doing the key piece wrong in the first place. Let's take those in reverse order.

---

Whatever you're doing in this line:

```
self.docs_list.append(self.__filter__(d))
```

… is likely wrong.

All you want to store for each document is a count vector. In order to get that count vector, you will need to append to a single dict of all words seen. Unless `__filter__` is modifying a hidden dict in-place, and returning a vector, it's not doing the right thing.

---

The main space savings in the BoW model come from not having to store copies of the string keys for each document, and from being able to store a simple array of ints instead of a fancy hash table. But an integer object is nearly as big as a (short) string object, and there's no way to predict or guarantee when you get new integers or strings vs. additional references to existing ones. So, really, the only advantage you get is `1/hash_fullness`; if you want any of the other advantages, you need something like an `array.array` or `numpy.ndarray`.

For example:

```
a = np.zeros(len(self.word_dict), dtype='i2')
for word in split_into_words(d):
    try:
        idx = self.word_dict[word]
    except KeyError:
        idx = len(self.word_dict)
        self.word_dict[word] = idx
        np.resize(a, idx+1)
        a[idx] = 1
    else:
        a[idx] += 1
self.doc_vectors.append(a)
```

---

But this *still* won't be enough. Unless you have on the order of 1K unique words, you can't fit all those counts in memory.

For example, if you have 5000 unique words, you've got 2M arrays, each of which has 5000 2-byte counts, so the most compact possible representation will take 20GB.

Since most documents won't have most words, you will get some benefit by using sparse arrays (or a single 2D sparse array), but there's only so much benefit you can get. And, even if things happened to be ordered in such a way that you get absolutely perfect RLE compression, if the average number of unique words per doc is on the order of 1K, you're still going to run out of memory.

---

So, you simply *can't* store all of the document vectors in memory.

If you can process them iteratively instead of all at once, that's the obvious answer.

If not, you'll have to page them in and out to disk (whether explicitly, or by using PyTables or a database or something).

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer. I am aware of the problem of storing the data in memory. Just wanted some guidelines for how to prevent it as you have given. I've re-implemented the methods and am now able to run the whole thing with some disk read/writes.